# How to update cron job schedule through user interface

Tags: google-app-engine

From gae document, I can set up the schedule in cron.yaml file as below :

every 5 minutes from 10:00 to 14:00

but when user wants to change start time and finish time, how can he do it through web interface?

Answer (score 1):

It's currently not possible. You can configure it only via configuration files like `cron.yaml` for python or `cron.xml` for Java.

Comment: This is valid even for a programmatically way? What if I need to create a cron through a servlet, for example?

Comment: @DevilingMaster that's a good question. My answer is based on the documentation and my own experience. The only way pointed in the doc is through the cron configuration files mentioned in the answer.